# What happens when you create an Explicit Inclusive managed path vs root SC subweb?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, managed-path

Hard to fit the exact question into the title, but given the following:

If you have a managed path with explicit inclusion i.e. `http://foo.com:123/bar` and you attempt to create a web on your root site called "bar" at `http://foo.com:123/bar` ... what happens?

And vice versa. If the web exists, what happens if you attempt to create this managed path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **"bar"** as managed path and you are trying to create a subsite under the root site collection (**"/"**) then it will throw the following errors.

> "bar" cannot be used as a site name. Site names cannot contain certain
>   reserved words and cannot begin with an underscore. Please enter a
>   different name.

But if you already created a web under root site called **"bar"**,and now trying to add new managed path for **Bar**. New managed pathw ill be created sucessfully but now if you go back and browse the **bar web**, you will get the `404 file not found` error.

Comment: I assume once creating the SC for /bar/ as a managed path, you will no longer get a 404. And I guess MSFT fixed what appeared to be an older problem of being able to mangle an entire site collection or managed path of site collections by disallowing you to create a sub-web on the root that conflicts with existing site collections?